# Ansible loop JSON array contains objects and replace each found element in JSON in file

Tags: json, loops, ansible

i have this JSON :

```
[{
        "${foo1}": "somevalue1",
        "${foo2}": "somevalue2"
    }, {
        "${zoo1}": "somevalue111",
        "${zoo2}": "somevalue222"
}]
```

In which i need to loop over in ansible and each object in the JSON array each key / pair value
I like to check if the key exists in the file and replace it with the value .
For example:
if in the file i have

```
key1=${foo1}
```

it will be replaced with

```
key1=somevalue1
```

i use to have hard coded ansible task :

```
replace:
    path: "/myfile.txt"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
  with_items:
    - { regexp: '${foo1}', replace: "new_value" }
```

i like to convert it to dynamically search and replace according to the given JSON

i capture the JSON like this : ( this is trim down YAML )

```
---
-
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  name: test
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ AAA| to_json }}"
    - name: set fact
      set_fact:
         multi_parms: "{{ AAA| to_json }}"
    - name: debug multi_parms
      debug:
        var: multi_parms
```

Comment: how are you telling `key1` should be your key? just having `key` string PLUS `index`? or can all the key names be `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the JSON file into a single dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_data: "{{ my_data|d({})|combine(item) }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'test.json') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_data:
    ${foo1}: somevalue1
    ${foo2}: somevalue2
    ${zoo1}: somevalue111
    ${zoo2}: somevalue222
```

Given an INI file, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat conf.ini
key1=${foo1}
key2=${foo2}
key3=xyz
```

parse the configuration into a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_ini: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(_vals)) }}"
      vars:
        _lines: "{{ lookup('file', 'conf.ini').splitlines() }}"
        _regex: '^(.*)=(.*)$'
        _keys: "{{ _lines|map('regex_replace', _regex, '\\1') }}"
        _vals: "{{ _lines|map('regex_replace', _regex, '\\2') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_ini:
    key1: ${foo1}
    key2: ${foo2}
    key3: xyz
```

Then use the module [ini_file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html#community-general-ini-file-tweak-settings-in-ini-files) to substitute the data, e.g.

```yaml
    - ini_file:
        path: conf.ini
        section:
        option: "{{ item }}"
        value: "{{ my_data[my_ini[item]] }}"
        no_extra_spaces: true
      loop: "{{ my_ini|list }}"
      when: my_ini[item] in my_data
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat conf.ini
key1=somevalue1
key2=somevalue2
key3=xyz
```

---

Q: *"**How can I do the search and replace in the destination file?**"*

A: See below the "--diff" output of each iteration.

```yaml
TASK [ini_file] ***************************************************
--- before: conf.ini (content)
+++ after: conf.ini (content)
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-key1=${foo1}
+key1=somevalue1
 key2=${foo2}
 key3=xyz

changed: [localhost] => (item=key1)
--- before: conf.ini (content)
+++ after: conf.ini (content)
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 key1=${foo1}
-key2=${foo2}
+key2=somevalue2
 key3=xyz

changed: [localhost] => (item=key2)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=key3)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, now that i have the key/values how can i do the search and replace in the destination file with them?

Comment: I've added the "--diff" output.

Comment: thanks, the problem im not using ini file , im using YAML file and Text file to do the search and replace , will it work ?

Comment: Both INI files and YAML files and Text files. In particular format. Instead of asking, you're expected to test the code and [edit] your question with [mre] if something goes wrong. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and the section "What are comments for, and when shouldn't I comment?" in particular.

Answer (score 0):

this code in j2 template

```
  {% for  item in json_data %}
    {% for k, v in item.items() %}
   
      key{{loop.index}}  =  {{ v }}
 
     {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
```

gets you this result

```
  key1  =  somevalue1

   key2  =  somevalue2

   key1  =  somevalue111

  key2  =  somevalue222
```

is this what you were looking for?

Comment: what is the j2 template? is it an ansible standart ?

Comment: yep, it is a jinja2 template. If you think the above answer is close to what you are expecting, I can post the whole playbook. I was not sure whether that met your needs.

Comment: look interesting, but how can i now do a search and replace in the destination file using replace task with all the key and values?

Comment: there is no replace in this approach. Basically, I am reading the data you have in your OP, and separating `key, value` and assigning hardcoded key to values

Comment: i see , how would you implement the replace after you have the key/value?